# What is "import Foundation" include in swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm using Xcode 6.2 and the default program has a line that states: "import Foundation". I was wondering what is included in the Foundation library?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/index.html

Comment: Got it! I couldn't find that for some reason. Thanks!